# Cruisecontrol Publish command onfailure

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, conditional-statements, publisher

I've got a problem publishing my current Project status.

Mapping:

```
<publishers>  
  <xmllogger /><!-- Log For WebDashboard ##Do not remove##-->    
  <email>
    ...
  </email>
  <onfailure>  
    <exec>
      <executable>echo ERROR > logs/status.txt</executable>
    </exec>
  </onfailure>            
</publishers>
```

When i want to start my Service i get the following message:

ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Config.ConfigurationException: 
Unable to instantiate CruiseControl projects from configuration document.
Configuration document is likely missing Xml nodes required for properly populating CruiseControl configuration.
Unable to load array item 'onfailure' - Cannot convert from type System.String to ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.ITask for object with value: "echo ERROR > logs/status.txt"

Does anyone know what that message means?

Thanks in anticipation

Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using CruiseControl or CruiseControl.NET?

If CC.NET, then the "onfailure" node does not exist. Instead you should use the Conditionnal Publisher[1] like this :

```
<conditionalPublisher>
    <conditions>
        <condition>Failure</condition>
    </conditions>
    <publishers>
        <exec>
            <executable>echo ERROR > logs/status.txt</executable>
        </exec>
    </publishers>
</conditionalPublisher>
```

You may also need to encapsulate your echo task in a cmd invokation :

```
<exec>
    <executable>cmd.exe</executable>
    <buildArgs>/c "echo ERROR > logs\status.txt"</buildArgs>
</exec>
```

[1] http://ccnetlive.thoughtworks.com/ccnet/doc/CCNET/Conditional%20Publisher.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've tried your solution, now i get the Error Message:
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Config.ConfigurationException: Unused node detected: <conditionalPublisher><conditions><condition>Failure</condition></conditions><publishers><exec>
<executable>echo ERROR &gt; logs/status.txt</executable></exec>
</publishers></conditionalPublisher>
I'm using version 1.5.7256.1

Comment: Sure, it works, im sorry i didnt knew that it's a subnode of publishers, very thanks to your supply. (:

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Executable+Task), it looks like `<executable>` has to be the name of the executable and the arguments must be passed in `<buildArgs>`. So something like this may do the trick.

```
<exec>
  <executable>echo</executable>
  <buildArgs>ERROR > logs/status.txt</buildArgs>
</exec>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, this doesnt solved my problem, same message :/

Comment: In connection with the Answer below, it worked, thank you. (: